# Open Graph tags not picked up by URL Linter or Facebook Like button

Tags: wordpress, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph

I know this question has been asked dozens of times before, I know because I've browsed this site as well as others extensively looking for an answer. I've tried all the tips I came across and I'm still completely puzzled (and growing more frustrated by the day).

Here is my homepage: http://teampowerpuffboys.com/ (it's a WordPress site, FWIW).
Here is an extract of the <head> containing the necesarry namespace declarations and OG tags:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html lang='en' xml:lang='en' xmlns:fb='http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml' xmlns:og='http://ogp.me/ns#' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="content-language" content="en" />
        <meta content='no-cache' http-equiv='Cache-Control' />
        <meta content='no-store' http-equiv='Cache-Control' />
        <title>Home | Team Powerpuff Boys | Real Men Wear Fuchsia!</title>
        <meta property="og:site_name" content="Team Powerpuff Boys" />
        <meta property="og:url" content="http://teampowerpuffboys.com/" />
        <meta name="title" content="Home | Team Powerpuff Boys" />
        <meta property="og:title" content="Home | Team Powerpuff Boys" />
        <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
        <meta property="og:image" content="https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-AemlgCQVQFA/TnS4miADMJI/AAAAAAAAAWE/_xrSA0ctNeU/logo.png" />
        <link rel="image_src" type="image/jpeg" href="http://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-AemlgCQVQFA/TnS4miADMJI/AAAAAAAAAWE/_xrSA0ctNeU/logo.png"/>
        <meta property="fb:admins" content="777890474" />
        <meta property="fb:app_id" content="164049423677441" />
```

Run it through the URL Linter and you get very unsatisfying results. (please copy and paste the url into the Linter to see the results, I can't provide the link  here since apparently I can only add 2 hyperlinks per post)

Here's the kicker: I copied the HTML of that page, pasted it to a static HTML page, and uploaded it here: http://teampowerpuffboys.com/test.html

The code in that page is EXACTLY the same except I added 'test.html' to the og:url tag to reflect the current page. But lo and behold, now I'm getting the desired output in URL linter!! (please copy and paste the url into the Linter to see the results, I can't provide the link  here since apparently I can only add 2 hyperlinks per post)

For the life of me I can't fathom what is the problem? Why does it work with a static HTML page but not a Wordpress page containing the exact same output?? Could this have something to do with WordPress permalinking? I've tried googling that but didn't get any more info. I've been dealing with this issue for over a month now but finally I'm at the end of my rope/patience and that's why I decided to finally post and hope that someone can point out a glaring omission in my code or logic. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Looks good to me: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fteampowerpuffboys.com%2F

Comment: Wow you really did blow my mind. I don't get it. It's been broken for WEEKS and now when I finally decide to ask for help it starts to work. If there is anything more annoying than a bug it's one that decides to fix itself without any intervention. Argh. Thanks though.